# How to remove polyline from the map on button click in Xamarin.Forms

Tags: c#, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am using `CustomMapRenderer.cs` and `ExtendedMap.cs` to draw `polylines` on the map with the tap (touch event).

`ExtendedMap.cs` is in the `MapTap (Portable)` project while the `CustomMapRenderer.cs` is in `MapTap.Android` project in the Visual Studio 2015  solution.

### CustomMapRenderer.cs

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using MapTap;
using MapTap.Droid;
using Xamarin.Forms;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;
using System;

[assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(ExtendedMap), typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]
[assembly: Dependency(typeof(CustomMapRenderer))]

namespace MapTap.Droid
{
    public class CustomMapRenderer : MapRenderer, IOnMapReadyCallback,ClearPolyline
    {
        GoogleMap map;
        List<LatLng> polygontest = new List<LatLng>();

        public CustomMapRenderer()
        {
        }

        protected override void OnElementChanged(Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.ElementChangedEventArgs<Map> e)
        {          
            if (map != null)
                map.MapClick -= googleMap_MapClick;
            base.OnElementChanged(e);
            if (Control != null)
                ((MapView)Control).GetMapAsync(this);
        }

        public void OnMapReady(GoogleMap googleMap)
        {
            map = googleMap;
            if (map != null)
                map.MapClick += googleMap_MapClick; ;
        }

        private void googleMap_MapClick(object sender, GoogleMap.MapClickEventArgs e)
        {
            polygontest.Add(new LatLng(e.Point.Latitude, e.Point.Longitude));
            ((ExtendedMap)Element).OnTap(new Position(e.Point.Latitude, e.Point.Longitude));           

            if (polygontest.Count >1 )
            {
                AddPolygons();               
            }
        }
        public void Clearline()
        {
           map.Clear();
        }

        void AddPolygons()
        {
           var polygonOptions = new PolylineOptions();

            polygonOptions.InvokeColor(0x66FF0000);

            foreach (var position in polygontest)
            {
                polygonOptions.Add(new LatLng(position.Latitude, position.Longitude));
            }

            map.AddPolyline(polygonOptions);
            polygontest.RemoveAt(0);
        }   
    }
}
```

### ExtendedMap.cs

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps;
using Xamarin.Forms.Maps.Android;
using Android.Gms.Maps;
using Android.Gms.Maps.Model;
using Xamarin.Forms;

namespace MapTap
{   
    public class ExtendedMap : Map
    {
        public event EventHandler<TapEventArgs> Tap;
        public ExtendedMap()
        {            
        }

        public ExtendedMap(MapSpan region) : base(region)
        {
        }

        public void OnTap(Position coordinate)
        {
            OnTap(new TapEventArgs { Position = coordinate });

            var lat = coordinate.Latitude;
            var lng = coordinate.Longitude;

            putpinonclick(lat,lng);
        }

        public void putpinonclick(double lat, double lng)
        {
            var pin = new Pin
            {
                Type = PinType.SavedPin,
                Position = new Position(lat, lng),
                Label = "Xamarin San Francisco Office",
                Address = "394 Pacific Ave, San Francisco CA"
            };

            this.Pins.Add(pin);           
        }

        protected virtual void OnTap(TapEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = Tap;
            if (handler != null) handler(this, e);
        }
    }

    public class TapEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public Position Position { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I want to clear polylines on button click (Clear Button) from the `MainPage.xaml`.

Following is a screenshot of the running application:
[Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zSpV5.jpg)

I am calling a function of `CustomMapRendrer.cs` from `MainPage.Xaml.cs` using

```
 var test = DependencyService.Get<ClearPolyline>();
                test.Clearline();
```

`ClearPolyLine` is an interface and `Clearline` in the function of interface which is implemented in `CustomMapRender`

The problem is that when I call the above line of code, the variable `test` itself is not `null`, but all of its member variables (implemented in `CustomMapRenderer`) are null. `test` is of type `ClearPolyline`.

How to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

`PolyLine addedLine = map.AddPolyline(polygonOptions);` 
This should return the added PolyLine so store this Ployline(s) in a property or collection. 
On button click or command disturb `RemovePolyline property` (Custom bindable property) of the ExtendedMap and listen to the property changes in the extended renderer and based on the value call `addedLine.remove();` or loop in the collection of polylines and remove it.